# What is variable p in open uri module in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

I am currently trying to parse a file in ruby and I ran into this example in the open uri module documentation (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html):

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
    f.each_line {|line| p line}
  }
```

Do you guys know what the variable p in "|line| p line" is?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a method, which you can clearly see because it takes an argument and variables cannot take an argument, only methods can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does the same than `puts` but calls `inspect` instead of `to_s` on the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
p() → nil
```

> For each object, directly writes obj.inspect followed by a newline to the program’s standard output.

That's method